# ng-repeat won't repeat array of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am pulling in a JSON file using Angular's $http, but I can't get the formatting right to use ng-repeat for an array of data.

For brevity's sake, here is a sample piece of what I'm working with...

```
{
 name:"Pete",
 phone: {
       brand: "Nexus",
       OS: "Android",
       contacts: [
          "Alexis",
          "Billy",
          "Chuck",
          "Danny"
       ]
   }
}
```

Then my ng code is

```
function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/my/url')
        .success(
                function(data){
                    $scope.contacts = data.phone.contacts;
```

and my HTML is

```
<div ng-repeat="names in contacts">
 {{names}}
</div>
```

Only it isn't returning anything. I feel like I am missing a set of [] somewhere?

Comment: In your json I see "conatacts" (notice the "a" after "con")...possibly a spelling mistake?

Comment: [This example shows it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hRmhQ9L79yFJYP9zwqr?p=preview). Are you able to show a full example that replicates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your demo. It made me realize that I had left out my controller from the div. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the as always quick responses. This was a case of sleep deprivation and overthinking things on my part and I left out the ng-controller for the div that the ng-repeat was in.

```
<div **ng-controller="myCtrl"** ng-repeat="names in contacts">
 {{names}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON:

```
conAtacts: [
          "Alexis",
          "Billy",
          "Chuck",
          "Danny"
       ]
```

On view:

```
<div ng-repeat="names in contacts">
 {{names}}
</div>
```

con**A**tacts != contacts

Also, you have missed one bracket in JSON.
Should be:

```
{
 name:"Pete",
 phone: {
       brand: "Nexus",
       OS: "Android",
       contacts: [
          "Alexis",
          "Billy",
          "Chuck",
          "Danny"
       ]
    }
}
```

Can it be reasons of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could simply be because you didn't respect the widely recommended practice of the 'point' when you use values that can evolve in AngularJS.

Create an object in the scope :

```
$scope.dataScope = {}
```

then in your method

```
function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/my/url')
        .success(
                function(data){
                    $scope.dataScope.contacts = data.phone.contacts;
```

and in your html

```
<div ng-repeat="name in dataScope.contacts">
   {{name}}
</div>
```